# Canon Imageclass MF216n printer

Tags: drivers, 16.04, canon

Ok I have had this printer since FEB and it will not accept information from the computer under Kubuntu 16:04.  It also would not under 1404 nor under UBUNTU 14.04 or 16.04 all of which I have tried to no avail.

I have installed the latest Cups drivers and the system recognizes the printer since when I turn it off and turn it on the printer settings screen on the computer tells me it is paused and off or disconnected.  When I turn it on the setting screen recognizes it as on and idle.

When I ask for a test page on the settings screen and on the printer que screen on the computer the system tells me it is sending data to the printer Then on the QUE screen after a few seconds the process completes and it is set as a completed job but 0 zero pages have been sent.

On the printer the processing data lights never come on at all and never have since I have had this printer.  Canon Tech finally told me that apparently the computer is never communicating the DATA with the printer.  Apparently this light should initially come on as soon as the data is initiated to be sent and then stay on while the transfer is completed until it prints.

So does anyone have any idea how to get the Linux system to send the data to this printer.  This is a really nice printer and it makes great copies so I would like to be able to PRINT with it.

Comment: Have you tried running the Linux specific drivers from canon?  http://www.canon.ca/inetCA/en/serviceDetail/method/load/id/5/sid/28/mid/2201135/type/D/opt/1

Comment: Try the MF4550 driver. This driver works on the MF4770. Go to Canon UK if you cannot find the 4550 driver the Canon US site.

Comment: Are you connecting over USB or a network?